# Python still use default version not Venv

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I have Ubuntu with already installed several Pythons:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7: Python 2.7.5
/usr/local/bin/python3.6: Python 3.6.10
/usr/local/bin/python3.6m: Python 3.6.10
```

All of them have no `jupyter` package.

So I have default commands `pip, pip3, pip3.6, python, python3, python3.6`
Also I have `venv` - virtual environment with `jupyter` installed.
I activate it using command:

```
source /home/me/venv/bin/activate
```

But `python` command still using python2, `python3` still use default python3.

I can't run python from venv and can't run `jupyter notebook`.

**How to run python from env and how to start jupyter notebook?**

---

I'm thinking about to rewrite alias for python link or maybe create new one, but don't know how to...

I can run go this way:
cd home/me/venv/bin
./python3

and here runs right python version (from venv) and i can import jupyter in interpreter. But still can't run `jupyter notebook` in cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute or relative paths and the `python -m MODULE` syntax to be explicit about which python interpreter you want to use.

```
/home/me/venv/bin/python -m pip install notebook
/home/me/venv/bin/python -m jupyter notebook
```

I do not know why the `activate` script is not working for you. It should prepend your venv `bin` folder to the `PATH` so the venv python and other executables are found before other executables on your system.

Comment: Thank you for response!
I can run `/home/me/venc/bin/python` but `jupyter` doesn't work this way:
`venv/bin/python -m jupyter notebook`:

Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Please see my updates. You need to install `notebook`.